# Getting the value of function of a class mocked in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a python script unittest using mock and patch where I have mocked a class.

```
class Class:
    def function():
        return 'something'

@patch('Class')
def test(MockClass):
    item = MockClass()
    self.assertEqual(item.function(), 'something)
```

When item.function is called, it returns a  object.
If I call it using item.function.return_value, it returns

Any idea how to get the actual value 'something' that item.function() should return?

Comment: format your code for reading visibility !

Answer (score 0):

actually it looks almost like example from [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide)

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class Class():
    def function(self):
        return 'something'

@patch('__main__.Class')
def test(MockClass):
    item = MockClass()
    item.function.return_value = 'something' 
    assert item.function() == 'something' 

test()
```